# Touchpad not supporting after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

I have a Lenovo 3430 3000 model laptop. USB mouse is supported by Ubuntu, but my touchpad is not supported. For Windows, I had to install Synaptics driver software to fully support touchpad. Is there any such package for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below command on terminal to install synaptics,

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

After installing the synaptics package,enable the touchpad by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> (where x represents (1-12) according to your configuration) will works.

Comment: I executed this command and even restarted my laptop, but still, my touchpad is not supported. I have even tried configuring the synaptiks management ...

Comment: did you have any seperate hardware switch for enabling touchpad?

Comment: I suppose it is available in F8 function key. Let me try ...