# touchpad stops working in HP 4515s

Tags: mouse, touchpad, hp

Sometimes it just stops working, usually when it's busy, not always. I'd like to get some code to reboot the touchpad, so I don't have to restart the computer every time. Maybe a driver that works or a permanent solution somehow. Anybody on the know here?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/a/389585/202806

Answer (score 0):

Try installing *Synaptiks* from the *Ubuntu Software Center* and everytime the touchpad stops working access it through the dash. Please let us know if that will work.